# Tela redimensionada após atualizar Xcode para versão 11

Tags: swift, xcode

Após atualizar o Xcode para versão 11, o App desenvolvido para Ipad não se comporta de forma maximizada na tela ao executar, tanto no simulador, quanto no dispositivo, porém na storyboard está perfeito.

Comment: Ele exibe a tela como um modal? faça um teste, rode o app, veja se vc consegue arrastar para baixo esse modal e se ele fecha a tela.

Comment: Se arrastar para baixo esse tela "modal" some, fica só essa tela azul do fundo. Por incrível que pareça o mesmo app abre perfeitamente no Xcode ver.10

Comment: Isso acontece pq a Apple mudou o modalpresentation no iOS13, nao é um problema do Xcode. Precisa mudar ele de automatic q é o padrão no iOS 13 para fullscreen.

Comment: Deu certo rray valeu

Comment: Antes:
---------
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController") as UIViewController
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
---------
Depois:
---------
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController") as UIViewController
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
---------

Answer (score 5):

A tela exibida como um modal (sheet) nāo é um problema do xcode 11, esse comportamento acontece a partir do iOS 13 e derivados (iPadOS) como anunciado na talk da WWDC de 2019 [Modernizing Your UI for iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/), começa aos 09:45 dura um pouco mais de 10 minutos.

O que mudou foi a propriedade `modalPresentationStyle` passou a assumir por padrão o valor `.automatic` isso exibe o viewcontroller como um modal e também adiciona um gesture para fechar que é acionado ao clicar e arrastar para baixo a tela.

## Resolução com storyboard/segue

Acesse o storyboard, selecione o segue e no attribute inspector (ícone em azul no topo), mude as propriedades:

- `kind` de `push` para `Present Modally`
- `Presentation` de `Same As Destination` para `Full Screen`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Resolução programática

1) Para deixar a tela em fullscreen como no iOS 12 basta definir `modalPresentationStyle` como `.fullScreen` no viewcontroller que será exibido.

```
@IBAction func mainClick(_ sender: Any) {
    if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") {
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

2) Pode contornar a situação evitando o gesture que oculta o view controller, ao definir `isModalInPresentation` como `true`, a tela ainda vai ter visual de uma aba.

```
@IBAction func mainClick(_ sender: Any) {
    if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") {
        controller.isModalInPresentation = true
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

## Delegates

Três novos métodos são oferecidos para manipular esse novo gesture através de `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate`.

- `presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss`: Ativado ao puxar a aba somente quando `isModalInPresentation` for `true`.
- `presentationControllerDidDismiss`: Ativado quando a aba já sumiu e `isModalInPresentation` for `false`.
- `presentationControllerWillDismiss`: Ativado ao iniciar o gesture (click e arrasto) e `isModalInPresentation` for `false`.

Exemplo:

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.presentationController?.delegate = self
        self.isModalInPresentation = false
    }
}

extension DetailsViewController: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
    func presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        print("Ao puxar a aba")
    }

    func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        print("Quando a aba já sumiu")
    }

    func presentationControllerWillDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        print("No inicio do gesture")
    }
}
```

## Leitura recomendada:

- [modalPresentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle)
- [UIModalPresentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle)
- [UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiadaptivepresentationcontrollerdelegate)